# different behavior of app when signed with production key

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I had a very bad surprise today. My app, once signed with the production key is not working in the same way as the default key signed by AndroidStudio.

Did anyone else have this issue before?

This is scary! :)

Comment: How so? Can you please provide a bit more information. If it is crashing, please supply a logcat output.

Comment: let me guess, it functions and breaks, and lags and pause.. is it something of that sort?

Comment: Are you using proguard while deploying the build ?

Comment: Vote to close.  Add more detail about what is different if you want help.

Comment: Hi Booger, I've just posted the answer below. Would you consider your down vote? The question was indeed short but the answer I believe might be valuable for others. Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I sorted out, but I was lucky to find so quickly because once the app is signed you cannot use the console anymore to debug your app... Anyway the reason behind this behavior change was that in my Gradle build script I've set the "minified" attribute  to "true" for the release build:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

At first sight, all is ok here, but check this out. I was executing in my code some stuff only if the current visible fragment was an instance of a class named "MyFragment":

```
Fragment fragment = getCurrentFragment();
// check if the current fragment is the one which is expected
if(fragment.getClass().getName().contains("MyFragment")) {
    // if yes, update the value of the edit text
    MyFragment mf = (MyFragment) fragment;
    mf.setEditTextText(string);
}
```

I finally was able to see that when I was minfying the code the line "fragment.getClass().getName()" was returning as a value "com.paul.MyFragment" if not minified and "com.paul.al.a" when minified.

I did not use the minification before, so I was absolutely not expecting a behvior change between the original and the minified code!

The conclusion so far for me is that if you want to minify your code you better do it in all the build versions you might need to avoid unpleasant surprises.

Any feedback is welcome!
Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Do you *have* to use the class name like that. It's not good practice even without considering the minified issue. Why don't you do `fragment.getClass().equals(MyFragment.class);`. Generally if refactoring your code breaks it its a very bad sign

Comment: Hi Richard! Thank you for this comment. You are absolutely right, this is a much better approach, I will do so. Thanks again! Paul :)